# On creation of a new file it shows "<SFML/Graphics.hpp> no such file or directory"

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml

Whenever I create a new file or class in code blocks and include Graphics header or any sfml header the compiler says no such file or directory.

When I work on a single file program works fine but when I create a new file and include the file in the same project then compiler starts showing errors.

It is showing this error:

> E:\codes\sfml_project\main.cpp:1:29: fatal error: SFML/Graphics.hpp: No such file or directory

I even tried installing `SFML 2.1` again and linking all the files to CodeBlocks but it is of no use.

Please help me out I have been trying to figure out the error for 2 days but couldn't correct it.

I first created the project in codeblocks which contains main.cpp file and code

```
    #include < SFML/Graphics.hpp >


    int main()

    {

        sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
        sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
        shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

        while (window.isOpen())
        {
             sf::Event event;
             while (window.pollEvent(event))
             {
                  if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                  window.close();
             } 

             window.clear();
             window.draw(shape);
             window.display();
        }

        return 0;
   }
```

this works fine then i created a new class World and from file->new->class in codeblocks and included a file SFML/Graphics.hpp

the World class looks like

World.hpp file contains code

```
    #ifndef WORLD_HPP
    #define WORLD_HPP

    #include < SFML/Graphics.hpp >
    class World
    {
        public:
        World();
        protected:
        private:
    };

    #endif // WORLD_HPP
```

and World.cpp file contains

```
    #include "World.hpp"

    World::World()
    {
         //ctor
    }
```

at this point only the compiler starts showing error

E:\codes\sfml_project\World.hpp:4:29: fatal error: SFML/Graphics.hpp: No such file or directory

And all the files ( World.hpp , World.cpp , main.cpp ) are in the same folder.

Comment: Please include a minimal example consisting of -- the contents of the source files, their location in the filesystem, the exact way in which you are invoking the compiler (run the compiler from the command-line to avoid IDE complexities), and the resulting error message. (Preferably you would also include the same information for the single-file case that is working for you.) You have clearly done something incorrectly, but there isn't enough information in the question to determine exactly what.

Comment: Thanx Mankarse for pointing this out. I have edited the Question and have tried my best to explain the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, though this may seem silly, make sure you've installed the dev package as well.

On a debian-based OS that is:
sudo apt-get install libsfml-dev

It's different from the rest of SFML. I bumped into the same issue, and that was my oversight. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler appears to be GCC. Assuming that `SFML/Graphics.hpp` is indeed in the compiler's
include-search paths, then your problem results from coding:

```
#include < SFML/Graphics.hpp >
```

instead of:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
```

The angle-brackets must enclose the header-name to be searched for,
and nothing else. If they enclose surplus spaces then the surplus
spaces are taken to be part of the header name.