# SFML On creation of new file: "<SFML/Graphics.cpp> no such directory"?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml

I seem to be getting an error when i add a new class file to my project in Codeblocks. It says it cannot find the SFML/Graphics.hpp directory? It works perfectly fine in my main class. 
Heres my code:

```
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>


class Game
{
  public: Game();
  void      run();

 private:
  void      processEvents();
  void      update(sf::Time deltaTime);
  void      render();
  void      handlePlayerInput(sf::Keyboard::Key key, bool isPressed);

 private:
    bool misMovingUp = false,
         misMovingDown = false,
         misMovingLeft = false,
         misMovingRight = false,
         misInFocus = true,
         hittingBorder = false;
    const float Game::PlayerSpeed = 100.f;
const sf::Time Game::TimePerFrame = sf::seconds(1.f/60.f);
    sf::RenderWindow mWindow;
    sf::Texture mTexture;
    sf::Sprite mPlayer;
};

#endif // GAME_H
```

Comment: inb4 Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24218348/on-creation-of-a-new-file-it-shows-sfml-graphics-hpp-no-such-file-or-director   Its not a dup, this question did not solve my problem.

Comment: Since the problem is quite vague, I can only recommend reading carefully and applying 1:1 the advice from the official tutorial. [SFML and Code::Blocks](http://sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/start-cb.php)

Comment: Fair enough, ill try reinstalling.

Answer (score 0):

**Ok so the problem was that:**
I had set my SFML compiler settings in my Codeblocks global compiler settings and not the project settings, which worked fine for the main class file but wouldn't work when i added files to the project. So i installed SFML in the build options of my project and it works fine now!